Day light saving in SMS using ampscript
We have written code Ampscript code to cover the day light savings for this year, but we need to update this code to work fork every year based on the day light saving dates(As day light saving dates changes every year)
Here is my ampscript code:
%%[

/* Get current year */

SET @ExistcurrentYear = DatePart(@Existing_Visit_Date, "year")

/* Start and End of Daylight Saving Time (DST) for ExistVisitDate */

SET @ExistdstStart = DateParse(CONCAT(@ExistcurrentYear, "-03-10"))  /* 2nd Sunday in March */

SET @ExistdstEnd = DateParse(CONCAT(@ExistcurrentYear, "-11-03"))  /* 1st Sunday in November */

/* Check if the current date is within the DST range */

 IF @Existing_Visit_Date >= @ExistdstStart AND 
@Existing_Visit_Date < @ExistdstEnd THEN
 SET @ExistisDST = 'TRUE'
ELSE 
SET @ExistisDST ='FALSE'
ENDIF

/* Adjust the date if DST is in effect */
IF @ExistisDST  == 'FALSE' 
THEN
SET @ExistadjustedDate = DateAdd(@Existing_Visit_Date, -1, "H")
 /* Add 1 hour for DST */
   ELSE
    SET @ExistadjustedDate = @Existing_Visit_Date
ENDIF
]%%


I can give you a limited workaround.

I am assuming you can establish a localtime.
("whose localtime"? >> This should be determined SFMC user setting in setup - meaning, local means it considers  what you as the logged in user have entered - double check this to be sure. my source is this and dim memories;)

Since you send SMS, I am assuming your local timezone is fixed due to shortcode etc also being limited to one country. So I believe you can likely can narrow your sendout down to one time zone, E.g. Central Europe, where DST means servertime +7 or +8 hours, depending on the time of year.

SFMC servertime is always UTC-6, DST is not observed


If all of the above is the case, then you can determine if it is summer or winter by comparing localtime to servertime.
This is a pretty clumsy solution, but in the above limits, it does the job and you do NOT have to update it every year.
SET @diffSummer = 8
SET @diffWinter = 7
SET @servertime = Now()
SET @localtime = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())

IF DateDiff(@servertime,@localtime, 'H') == @diffSummer THEN
    SET @diff = @diffSummer  
ELSEIF DateDiff(@servertime,@localtime, 'H') == @diffWinter THEN
    SET @diff = @diffWinter
ELSE
    SET @diff = 0
    /* this case obviously doesnt really work, but you can control for it not happening given the limits described. */

ENDIF

Now you get a resulting @diff as a number.
It's the difference in hours, in the central europe case either 7 or 8 of UTC-6 (servertime) to localtime, which you can DateAdd ()to whatever date.
